# Skrollr: manipulate html5 data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, skrollr

I've written a Javascript/jQuery function for dynamically writing HTML5 data attributes into some HTML tags and making [Skrollr plugin](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) work. I am unable to use jQuery .data() because it only stores (it does not write inside the tags) attributes. Here is my code:

```
parallaxData();
window.addEventListener('resize', parallaxData);

function parallaxData(){

    if ($(window).width() > 768 && imgContainer.length) { 

        var imgContainerJS = document.getElementById('big-image'),
            captionJS = document.getElementById('caption'),
            headerJS = document.getElementById('header');        

        imgContainerJS.dataset.top = 'transform:translateY(0px);'
        imgContainerJS.dataset.topBottom = 'transform:translateY(' + '-' + imgHeight/4 + 'px);' 
        captionJS.dataset.anchorTarget = "#big-image-wrap"
        captionJS.dataset.top = 'transform:translateY(0px);' 
        captionJS.dataset.topBottom = 'transform:translateY(' + '-' + imgHeight/8 + 'px);'
        headerJS.dataset.anchorTarget = "#big-image-wrap"
        headerJS.dataset.top = 'transform:translateY(0px);' 
        headerJS.dataset.topBottom = 'transform:translateY(' + '-' + imgHeight/4 + 'px);' 

        var animDone = false;
        skrollr.init({
            forceHeight: false,
            smoothScrolling: false,     
            render: function() {
                if ( header.hasClass('skrollable-after') ) {
                    if ( ! animDone ) {
                        animDone = true;
                        header.addClass('fixed-header').css({
                            'display' : 'none'
                        }).fadeIn(300);   
                    }
                } else {
                    animDone = false;
                    header.removeClass('fixed-header');
                }
            }           
            }).refresh();

        imgCaption.css({ position: 'fixed' });
        singleImg.css({ position: 'fixed' });

    } else if ($(window).width() > 768) {

        $('#content').css({ marginTop: headerHeight + 'px' });
        imgCaption.css({ position: 'fixed' });
        singleImg.css({ position: 'fixed' });

    } else {

        skrollr.init().destroy();
        $('#content').css({ marginTop: 0 + 'px' });

        var parallaxEls = $('header, #big-image, #caption'),
            attrs = parallaxEls[0].attributes,
            name,
            index;
        for (index = attrs.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
            name = attrs[index].nodeName;
            if (name.substring(0, 5) === "data-") {
                parallaxEls.removeAttr(name);
            }
        }   

        parallaxEls.css({
            '-webkit-transform' : '',
            '-moz-transform' : '',
            'transform' : '',
            'backgroundPosition' : ''
        }).removeClass('skrollable-after');

        imgCaption.css({ position: 'absolute' });
        singleImg.css({ position: 'absolute' });

    }

}
```

I am wondering if there's a chance to achieving the same result only using jQuery, also because I need to select elements by class and not by ID.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with jQuery. It is possible to add attributes to img or div or whatever.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".yourclass").attr({
         "data-450": "exampleCSS:examplechange;",
         "data-500": "exampleCSS:examplechange;"});
});
```

I tried it with one of my div's from my code and the element is not visible, but the attributes are added, I can see it in firebug

---

The other divs are still scrolling so I messed it up somewhere else.

---

Hope it helped you (even when you asked months ago). If you already found an answer, please share your solution

Comment: Yes, in the end I've used .attr

Thanks anyway!